# Dividing Consecutive float numbers in a list

Tags: python, parsing

Hey just coming back to python for the some homework, and i'm able to figure out how to divide consecutive numbers in a list. I've tried using slices, and adding another range to subscript the numbers like below.

```
x, y = vec_time()
for ii in y:
    for jj in range(1-101):
        print(ii[jj+1]/ii[jj])
```

My Y list looks like this buy 20 times longer.

```
[0.014009237289428711, 0.017012834548950195, 0.020015716552734375, 0.019011974334716797, 0.01801300048828125,
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `numpy` and do the following

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(your_list)
result = arr[:-1]/arr[1:]
```

This gives the following for

```
your_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
result = [1.0/2.0,2.0/3.0, 3.0/4.0,4.0/5.0]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! forgot how numpy can basically everything haha

Comment: I definitely surprised by how complete numpy can be sometimes!